# How can I filter node references to 'strictly own nodes' ? (Drupal 7)

Tags: drupal, reference, cck

On my drupal 7 site, I have a content type (artwork) that presents my users with a CCK field where they can specify what project (another content type) the node is referenced to (node reference module). The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to filter the options to 'own nodes only', so all the projects of all the users show up it in the list, and any user can just push his nodes on the nodes of another. I can still filter these nodes out with views on the output of the project node, but it's not very clean on the add/node form.
I found a module that is called 'CCK reference filter' that sounds like it should handle this situation, but it's not ported to Drupal 7.

So far I've gone pretty far without having to touch template.php and using hooks, and I would be very relieved if I wouldn't have to, since I'm hardly a php wizard... But if someone has any suggestions! Everything is welcome

Have a good day!
Bruno

(this is my first post here by the way, please tell me if I'm in the wrong place or anything)

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve that in Drupal 6 was to use a Views to filter the node that you can reference.

The goal for References module in Drupal 7 is to strictly have the same functionality as the D6 module. But References is still in developpment and it seems that this has not been implemented for now.

This issue seems to be very similar to what to want : http://drupal.org/node/1034042

Comment: Hello Haza, thanks for your reply. It seems logical enough to use the filters provided in views, and it's one of the options I investigated, but I can't seem to find information on how to use views on forms!